# What is the trick to getting a background to expand past the container?

Tags: sass, susy-compass

I have a main content div, nesting a content and sidebar div. My content section is a background-color, that I want to go all the way to the left of the screen, but stop where I have set it column wise, which is at 8.

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#content { 
  @include span-columns(8, 12);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#sidebar { @include span-columns(4 omega, 12); }
```

I tried the bleed mixin, giving it something like 10000px, but that scrunched all my content up. Anything I can do to achieve what I am after? thanks!

Comment: Eric, sorry about that. I feel even more dumb ha. Fixed the link. Basically, I want the background of my content div, to go all the way to the left edge of the screen, out side of the left of the container. I don't want it to go full screen, just start from the left, and stop when the content stops after the 8 columns.

Comment: That image has a black background that extends to both edges. What am I missing?

Comment: http://grab.by/jUFy

i added a better picture, with a lighter background and highlight of columns. The main background is a black texture image, and content is just a black color with opacity. Imagine where the color ends on the left to be the left side of the monitor. The black bars on both sides of the image are not part of the page, just Fireworks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see. I can imagine a few ways to do this, but all of them require a bit of creativity. The old (original) Susy site actually created this effect using the bleed approach. That would work something like this:

```
.container { @include container; }

#content {
  @include span-columns(8, 12);
  @include bleed(200%, left);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#sidebar { @include span-columns(4 omega, 12); }
```

What problems were you seeing with that approach?

Comment: thanks, Eric. Here is a screen shot of what happens when I use bleed: http://grab.by/jXo2

Everything smushes together for some reason.

Comment: I would need to see more of your code to know for certain, but here's my guess: You are using an older version of the `bleed` mixin, and also using `box-sizing: border-box`. You will need to use `content-box` sizing on any element that bleeds - and the lastest mixin takes care of that for you: https://gist.github.com/ericam/4973348

Comment: Yes! Eric, you are a genius. Thank you so much for your help. Funny how 1 property can make or break like that. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm..curious, if you don't mind, but is it possible to do the same in the opposite direction? Let's say I did it to the right sidebar, and applied bleed to the right side of the screen. It adds scrollbars if it goes too far, so I wonder if that would take javascript

Comment: You can do it , as long as you are willing to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the html/body tags. If your site is not completely responsive, you may want to be careful with this.